# Heroku logs - seeing alternate logs only

Tags: python, logging, heroku

I am profiling certain python functions on heroku app using memory_profiler

I am seeing only the alternate lines of the profiler output only. How can I see all the lines?

```
2014-11-06 14:24:17.774983+00:00 app worker.1 - - [2014-11-06 14:24:17,774: WARNING/Worker-2] 339 65.3 MiB 0.0 MiB 'percentile_speed_lower': percentile_speed_lower,
2014-11-06 14:24:17.776512+00:00 app worker.1 - - [2014-11-06 14:24:17,776: WARNING/Worker-2] 341 65.3 MiB 0.0 MiB 'percentile_speed_upper': percentile_speed_upper,
2014-11-06 14:24:17.777907+00:00 app worker.1 - - [2014-11-06 14:24:17,777: WARNING/Worker-2] 343
2014-11-06 14:24:17.779243+00:00 app worker.1 - - [2014-11-06 14:24:17,778: WARNING/Worker-2] 345
2014-11-06 14:24:17.780590+00:00 app worker.1 - - [2014-11-06 14:24:17,780: WARNING/Worker-2] 347 65.3 MiB 0.0 MiB try:
2014-11-06 14:24:17.781899+00:00 app worker.1 - - [2014-11-06 14:24:17,781: WARNING/Worker-2] 349 # print kwargs['activity_type']
2014-11-06 14:24:17.783245+00:00 app worker.1 - - [2014-11-06 14:24:17,782: WARNING/Worker-2] 351
2014-11-06 14:24:17.784693+00:00 app worker.1 - - [2014-11-06 14:24:17,784: WARNING/Worker-2] 353 # activity exists
2014-11-06 14:24:17.786208+00:00 app worker.1 - - [2014-11-06 14:24:17,785: WARNING/Worker-2] 355 # TrackedFitnessActivity.objects.filter(uid=uid).update(**kwargs)
2014-11-06 14:24:17.787666+00:00 app worker.1 - - [2014-11-06 14:24:17,787: WARNING/Worker-2] 357 122.8 MiB 0.0 MiB pass
2014-11-06 14:24:17.789008+00:00 app worker.1 - - [2014-11-06 14:24:17,788: WARNING/Worker-2] 359 122.5 MiB -0.2 MiB gc.collect()
```

Comment: Have you tried https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/logging/

Comment: Yes, I checked it now. there is nothing out there that can turn on / off logging every alternate line